# Img src for adding photo from desktop to html code not working

Tags: html, image

I have the following code

```
<html>

<body>

<img src = "part3.png" />

</body>


</html>
```

However, the photo is not being displayed correctly on any browser: Google Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer... etc. Both my html file, and the photo (.png) are in the same Directory: C:\users\fmadrid\Documents

The only thing that I am getting on the web page is a logo of a photo. Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Remove the spaces around the `=` and you should be fine

Comment: Can you post screenshot of file/dir structure? Also, verify the name of the file, it should be exactly same as mentioned in html.

Answer (score 0):

The html file you have created should be saved in the same path where the image is stored.